# Average number of correctly answered questions in a quiz

Tags: javascript, math

I have a quiz app that asks 3 questions. I track correct/incorrect answers over time as follows:

```
var c0 = 143; // Number of users who got 0 questions correct
var c1 = 278; // Number of users who got 1 question  correct
var c2 = 236; // Number of users who got 2 questions correct
var c3 = 185; // Number of users who got 3 questions correct
```

How can I calculate the *average* number of questions that user's got right?

```
var averageCorrectQuestions = 2.15; // Example (out of 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply the count with the count of correct questions, sum this value and count all users. As result divide the sum by count.

```js
var c0 = 143,
    c1 = 278,
    c2 = 236,
    c3 = 185,
    [sum, count] = [c0, c1, c2, c3].reduce(([s, c], n, v) => [s + n * v, c + n], [0, 0]);
    
console.log(sum, count);
console.log(sum/count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to calculate sum and a function to get the average:

```
function sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((s, next) => s + next, 0)
}

function average(arr) {
    return (arr.length ? sum(arr) / arr.length : 0)
}
```